# Monotouch Garbage Collectiton Not Working - Bug?

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios

I have an application that displays an infinite amount of ViewControllers and animates to each new one, after about 30 VC's the application crashes due to lack of memory. After further experimenting, I have discovered that the destructor on the ViewController instance is never called.

```
~TargetPromptController(){
   Console.WriteLine("Destructor Called!");
 }
```

Code to transition to new VC:

```
public void PageFlipRight(UIViewController aController) {

      aController.View.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, 659, 630);
      aController.ViewWillAppear(true);
      if (activeRightController != null) activeRightController.ViewWillDisappear(true);
      rightView.AddSubview(aController.View);
      if (aController.View is BaseRightView)
           ((BaseRightView)aController.View).SetLocation(new PointF(0, 0),                           CurrentOrientation);
      aController.ViewDidAppear(true);

      UIView.BeginAnimations(null);
      UIView.SetAnimationDuration(1.0);
      UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.CurlUp, rightView, true);
      UIView.CommitAnimations();

      NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500),
             delegate {
                  if (activeRightController != null) {
                      activeRightController.View.RemoveFromSuperview();
                      activeRightController.ViewDidDisappear(true);
                      activeRightController.Dispose();
                    }
                  activeRightController = aController;
                  GC.Collect();
                });
}
```

I have tried everything. Manually calling `GC.Collect()`, Manually calling `Dispose()` on all subviews, removing subviews, unregistering event handlers...nothing seems to get the VC to release it's memory. Is there a way I can manually release it? Or is there something else I am missing? Extremely frustrated, I welcome any help.

Comment: Hard to say at a glance, but events (where your object is the ***target*** are the classic cause

Comment: One possible solution is to just save and reused previously discarded view controller objects, similar to what's done with table view cells.

Comment: It's not only a possible solution, it's probably the better solution. There's a reason the UITableView doesn't just alloc/dealloc cells but reuse them - the latter is far more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell what your code is doing with that snippet, but if your finalizer is not being called is due to two reasons:

(a) When you call Dispose() manually, this releases the resources, and then calls GC.SupressFinalize (standard Dispose pattern).   This prevents finalizers from running, including yours, so you would have never seen it.

(b) If this did not happen even if you take out your Dispose is because someone still has a reference to it.

Now, perhaps what you need is not to animate UIViewControllers, but Views instead.   What you seem to be doing behind the UIViewController's back looks nasty, and your code could just be clearer merely have an AnimatedUIViewController that happens to manage multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you're getting called DidReceiveMemoryWarning method on your controllers. If yes you should release some memory on your views that are currently not visible.